# Efficient Marionette sorted CollectionView for multiple attributes

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, marionette

I am trying to find a way to efficiently display a sorted Marionette.CollectionView, sorted by multiple attributes **without modifying the underlying Backbone collection**.  For this example, I am using 'name' and 'online' attributes, and want my CollectionView to be displayed in 2 parts:

- online, alphabetically
- offline, alphabetically

I have a single Collection of Backbone.Models and want to use this across my web application.  So having a sort function on my Collection doesn't feel right to me.

My example code is as follows:

```
var MyCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
  model:Backbone.Model
});

var myCollection = new MyCollection();

myCollection.set([
  { name : 'Freddy', online : true },
  { name : 'Zorro', online : false },
  { name : 'Charlie', online : false },
  { name : 'Alice', online : true }
]);

var MyView = ... 
/* 
 omitted for brevity, though my template is like
 <li>{{name}} {{#if online}}(Online){{/if}}</li>
*/

var MyCollectionView = Marionette.Collection.extend({
  childView:MyView,
  viewComparator: function (item1, item2) {

    var item1Online = item1.get('online');
    var item2Online = item2.get('online');
    if (item1Online != item2Online)
      return item1Online ? -1 : 1;

    var item1Name = item1.get('name');
    var item2Name = item2.get('name');
    return item1Name.localeCompare(item2Name);
  }
});

var myCollectionView = new MyCollectionView({collection:myCollection});

appView.getRegion('example').show(myCollectionView);
```

I would like this to be displayed as:

- Alice (Online)
- Freddy (Online)
- Charlie
- Zorro

This is fine when all of the data is added to the collection at once, or add/remove events but if one of the attributes is updated on a model that is already in the collection, the view does not update.

---

If Charlie's 'online' property changed to true - e.g by performing.

```
charlieModel.set('online', true)
```

I would like the CollectionView to have rendered automatically as:

- Alice (Online)
- Charlie (Online)
- Freddy (Online)
- Zorro

Any suggestions? Many thanks in advance.

Comment: I've always wondered the best way to do this in Backbone, but 1) fear not having a sort method, it isn't wrong.  2) combined with the .clone() method, you can freely sort a copy of a collection without mutating it's source.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Marionette team advised having a separate Backbone collection behind the scenes, rather than using the `viewComparator` on the `CollectionView`.

Using [reorderOnSort](http://marionettejs.com/docs/v2.4.2/marionette.collectionview.html#collectionviews-reorderonsort) on the `CollectionView` made a huge difference (at least 10x speed up) in terms of render speed.

> This option is useful when you have performance issues when you resort your CollectionView.
>   Without this option, your CollectionView will be completely re-rendered, which can be
>   costly if you have a large number of elements or if your ChildViews are complex. If this option
>   is activated, when you sort your Collection, there will be no re-rendering, only the DOM nodes
>   will be reordered.

My final example code:

```
  var MyView = Backbone.Marionette.ItemView.extend({
    modelEvents:{
     'change:name change:online': 'render'
    },
    template:template
  });

  var MyCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    initialize : function(){
      this.on('change:name change:online', this.sort, this);
    },
    comparator : function(item1, item2){
      var item1online = item1.get('online');
      var item2online = item2.get('online');
      if (item1online != item2online)
        return item1online ? -1 : 1;

      return item1.get('name').localeCompare(item2.get('name'));
    }
  });

  var myCollection = new MyCollection();

  var MyCollectionView = Marionette.CollectionView.extend({
    childView : MyView,
    reorderOnSort : true
  });  

  var myCollectionView = new MyCollectionView({
    collection : myCollection
  });

  appView.region('example').show(myCollectionView);
```

Answer (score 1):

From the [backbone documentation](http://backbonejs.org/)

> Collections with a comparator will not automatically re-sort if you later change model attributes, so you may wish to call sort after changing model attributes that would affect the order.

You can put somewhere convenient in your code a listener on a change in the model attributes your are targeting that will trigger a re-sort of your collection.

```
// for example in your collection
initialize: function() {
    this.on('change:name', function() { this.sort() }, this);
}
```